# Express not finding route

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following routes defined in Angular:

```
export class CartService {
  private cartAddUrl = "/api/cart/add";
  private cartGetUrl = "/api/cart/get";
  private cartCountUrl = "/api/cart/count";
}
```

Calls to the Node server using the first two variables work as expected. Calls using the cartCountUrl result in a 404 error, the route is not found.

This is the function that uses the cartCountUrl:

```
public getNumberOfItems() {
   return this.httpClient.get<number>(this.cartCountUrl)
   .pipe(
     tap(count => console.log('count', count)),
     map(count => this.numberOfItems = count)
   )
 }
```

The routes are defined on Node as follow:

```
'use strict';

var ctrlCart = require('../controllers/cart.server.controller');
var ctrlUser = require('../controllers/user.server.controller');

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.route('/api/cart/add')
    .post(ctrlUser.authenticate, ctrlCart.cartAdd);

    app.route('/api/cart/get')
   .get(ctrlUser.authenticate, ctrlCart.cartGet);

    app.route('/api/cart/count')
    .get(ctrlUser.authenticate, ctrlCart.cartCount);

}
```

Again, the first two routes are found. The '/api/cart/count' route results in 404 error.

cart.server.controller:

```
exports.cartCount = function(req, res) {
    Cart.findOne({pasword: req.password})
    .exec(function(err, cart) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('error get cart count');
            res.status(500).json(err);
            return;
        } else if(!cart) {
            res.status(404).json(0);
        } else {
            console.log('cart count', cart.cartItem.length);
            res.status(200).json(cart.cartItem.length);
            return;
        }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Can you include the contents of `cart.server.controller` ?

Comment: cart.server.controller included.

Comment: @Juan you pointed in the right direction. There was a typo in the controller -- password was spelled incorrectly. Strange that node would report this as 404.

Comment: it had to be there! I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo. In the controller, "password" was spelled with one 's'.
Cart.findOne({pasword: req.password})

I don't understand why node would report this as a routing error.

Comment: You weren't getting a 404 because of no route being found. You were getting it because of this line: `res.status(404).json(0);` (combined with the typo you mentioned in this answer).